# jQuery fadeToggle on invisibl element

Tags: jquery

In Jquery docs fadeToggle is working When called on a visible element, what if I want to start my element on zero opacity. Is there a way to solve this or any other method to use.
I don't want to use display: none

```
<h2>toggle</h2>

<div class="box">box</div>

.box {
   opacity: 0;
}

$('h2').click(function(){
   $('.box').fadeToggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/A6PWN/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('h2').click(function() {
    var boxOpacity = parseInt($('.box').css('opacity'));
    $('.box').animate({
        opacity: boxOpacity == 0 ? 1 : 0
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/A6PWN/4/

This is using opacity, not display: none;

Edit:My bad .. updated it to work with the box. :D

Comment: This is perfect, Thanks Kaloyan

Answer (score 1):

put `display:none` as style of the box and remove the `opacity:0` from the css

your code should look like:

```
<h2>toggle</h2>
<div class="box" style="display:none">box</div>
```

and the CSS

```
.box {
   /* no opacity here */
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use display: none

Comment: then you probably have to go with Kaloyan Ivanov's answer

Answer (score 0):

`fadeToggle();` make element styled `display:none;` try to using `animate();` if you dont want to 'realy' disappearing the element; this: http://jsfiddle.net/A6PWN/1/

```
$("h2").click(function () {
  $(".box").animate({
    opacity: 1,
  });
});
```

Comment: What if I want to hide the box again

Comment: @Kaloyan's answer better than mine :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set opacity to 1 first

```
.css('opacity', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
$('h2').click(function(){
    $('.box').css('opacity', 1);
    $('.box').fadeToggle();
});
```